# How exactly IAppBuilder.CreatePerOwinContext<T> should be used?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, owin

I'm confused on how the OWIN CreatePerOwinContext method is to be used. As far as I can see it's a poor mans DI mechanism. Yet, I fail to see how to use it.

We can register a type/implementation at the Startup sequence like:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<IUserService>(() => {
     return new UserService() as IUserService;
});
```

Then how do we resolve to that later on. Documentation says it can be retrieved via Get method. But `Get<T>` expects a string parameter, which is the key to that entry in the Enviornment IDictionary? How can I know the key in this case?

```
IUserService userService = context.Get<IUserService>(???);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `typeof` to get the `key` parameter:

```
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).ToString());
```

Also, `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin` assembly contains the parameterless version of `Get<T>()` method, so you can use it if you already have ASP.NET Identity in your project.

Comment: This answer pointed me in the right direction. However, if you want take the item with the key, we have to prefix the AssemblyQualifiedName with 'AspNet.Identity.Owin:', giving just the fully qualified type name will not work

Comment: I dont think this works.  I inspected the ctx.Environment Property Keys and it appears that the key added is a fully qualified assembly name by changing to typeof(ApplicationDbContext).AssemblyQualifiedName.  I love how the owin documentation mentions none of this.

Answer (score 3):

I have a more correct answer after running into this myself, trying to implement the code within this stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31918218

So given this initialization code within the conventional Configure method:

```
static void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    //https://stackoverflow.com/a/31918218
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<AppBuilderProvider>(() => new AppBuilderProvider(app));

    ConfigureAuth(app); //note implementation for this is typically in separate partial class file ~/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs
}
```

One can retrieve the instance created by this code:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction() 
{
    //https://stackoverflow.com/a/31918218
    var app = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<AppBuilderProvider>("AspNet.Identity.Owin:" + typeof(AppBuilderProvider).AssemblyQualifiedName).Get();
    var protector = Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection.AppBuilderExtensions.CreateDataProtector(app, typeof(Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthAuthorizationServerMiddleware).Namespace, "Access_Token", "v1");
    var tdf = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.TicketDataFormat(protector);
    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(ci, null);
    var accessToken = tdf.Protect(ticket);

    //you now have an access token that can be used.
}
```

Comment: Looking back, it might have been easier to create the protector in Startup.Auth and inject it into OwinContext