# How do I access the OWIN instance per request DbContext in my action methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin, owin-middleware

I never even noticed this code:

```
    ' Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(AddressOf ApptDbContext.Create)
```

So I had even written a `DbContext` filter, to create and dispose an instance at the beginning and end of a request.

Now that it looks like OWIN does this for me, how do I access the `DbContext` that it takes care of?

The accepted answer to the question [How exactly IAppBuilder.CreatePerOwinContext should be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32501238/8741) does not work for me, there is no parameterless `Get()`, and using just the `AssemblyQualifiedName` of the type returns null.

Comment: Think this answers the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32501238/how-exactly-iappbuilder-createperowincontextt-should-be-used

Comment: Just go with `Request.GetOwinContext().Get<AppDbContext>()`

Comment: Thanks, @MarcusH. This is then a duplicate.